# Разделить новости по категориям и получить 2 страницы?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт, будет раздел новостей и раздел блога( да это разные вещи ). Блог создал стандартным способом через записи. Новости думаю создать как отдельный вид записи. А возможно ли просто это разделение сделать через рубрики WP. Т.е при создания записи определять новость это или запись блога. По своему дизайну они не отличаются ничем. Единственный момент что вывод всех новостей и вывод всех постов блога отличаются немного по дизайну. Как можно тогда кастомизировать? Или проще и лучше создать через Custom Post Type новости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отличий в выводе мало, можно обойтись стандартными постами и рубриками. Для этого в `single.php` используйте проверку на принадлежность конкретного поста к определённой рубрике. Для этого существует условная [функция](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) `has_category( $category, $post )`.

```
$is_news_post = has_category( 'news' );
$is_blog_post = has_category( 'blog' );
```

В нужных местах используйте эти переменные в качестве условия для вывода различающихся частей разметки:

```
if ( $is_news_post ):
    // Выводим что-то для новостей
elseif ( $is_blog_post ):
    // Выводим что-то для блога
endif;
```

Сами рубрики можно кастомизировать на уровне шаблонов, выделив под новости `category-news.php`. Или, если различия минимальны, опять-таки задействовать в общем шаблоне `category.php` [соответствующий условный тег](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) `is_category('news')`, чтобы выдать разную разметку.

Если же шаблон новости по задумке сильно отличается от шаблона обычного блогового поста или вы планируете очень разветвлённую рубрикацию, то тогда становится проще [зарегистрировать дополнительный тип поста](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) `register_post_type()` и, возможно, [создать соответствующую таксономию](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) `register_taxonomy()`.

Иногда второй вариант, помимо технических причин, используется для удобства контент-менеджера — он позволяет вывести раздел новостей в корень меню админки и не путаться в рубриках при публикации и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

> Новости думаю создать как отдельный вид записи. А возможно ли просто
>   это разделение сделать через рубрики WP.

Нужно сделать отдельный тип контент со своей таксонимией.
В помощь маны:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/#custom-post-types
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy
Генератор: https://generatewp.com/post-type/

Можно также использовать [плагины](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Custom+Post+Types/).

> Как можно тогда кастомизировать?

Соответствующими шаблонами темы.